# Store object in Felix framework

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I have a application with many bundles. It turns out that I need to use imports from may bundles and I get warning from maven that three is loop in bundles dependencies.

```
The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='bundle1'}' and 'Vertex{label='bundle1'}' introduces to cycle in the graph .................
```

To solve the import issue is there any was to store Object in Apache Felix framework which I can insert and use it in every bundle?

Answer (score 0):

So you mean an object instance? You can publish an object instance as an OSGi service.

Comment: Yes, but then again the bundles will have maven dependency and I again get the same problem.(am I correct?)

Comment: Yes .. you need to share a class or interface as a maven dependency. Simply make sure the shared module does not depend on other modules then you should have no cycles.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial about OSGi and OSGi services some time ago. See http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/02/15/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+1+-+Installation+and+First+application . There you can see how to handle the shared module (the model in my case) and how to publish and consume the service.